# <InputArtifactName>::<TemplateFileName> What does this InputArtifactName and TemplateFileName exactly mean?

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I am trying to build AWS codepipeline. And I am unsure how to specify the Template. It says it must be in this format

```
<InputArtifactName>::<TemplateFileName>.
```

Comment: The pipeline is to build using Cloudformation directly from a CodeCommit repo.

Answer (score 0):

The input artifact is a ZIP file that contains your CloudFormation template (likely produced by a source or CodeBuild action). The template file name is the path in the ZIP file to your CloudFormation template.

Here's the documentation for the CloudFormation CodePipeline action: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html